# Apache 500 error without output in Eclipse console

Tags: java, json, eclipse, rest, tomcat

Getting a 500 error in Apache Tomcat 8.

With this text (styled the way that Tomcat does):

> HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error
>       type Status report
>
> message Internal Server Error
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it
>   from           fulfilling this request.
>
> Apache Tomcat/8.0.20

Tomcat is being run from Eclipse Luna.

The pertinent code that I am using is this:

```
@GET
@Path("-{index}")
@Produces({"application/json"})
public MyCustomModelObject getDataByIndex(@PathParam("index") int index){
    return ArrayOfMyCustomModelObjects[index];
}
```

The JSON data is not returned, but instead the 500 page is returned, but NO further message is output.
In addition, no error is output to the Eclipse console.

*However*, if I change the @Produces to

```
@Produces({"application/xml"})
```

It returns the xml just fine.

Any help in solving this would be appreciated.

Happy to provide further information to help troubleshoot.

EDIT:

```
import java.util.Date;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement
public class MyCustomModelObject {

    @XmlElement(name = "categories")
    private String[] category;
    @XmlElement(name = "")
    private String author;
    @XmlElement(name = "date")
    private Date date;

    public MyCustomModelObject(){};

    public MyCustomModelObject(String[] category, String author,
            Date date) {
        super();
        this.category = category;
        this.author = author;
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String[] getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String[] category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the implementation of ArrayOfMyCustomModelObjects.

Comment: To debug, write an [`ExceptionMapper<Throwable>`](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/representations.html#d0e6559). Print the stack trace the the exception. I'm thinking this should give you more information about the problem. Please post the stacktrace afterwords, if there is one.

Comment: And why do you have an empty element name `@XmlElement(name = "")`?

Comment: @peeskillet I noticed that just a minute or two before you posted your comment. I tested and it fixed the problem, then when I was writing the answer (to my own silly mistake) I saw your comment. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I had an empty string in the @XmlElement tag (name="") for one of the fields.
Once I gave it a name, the problem went away, and JSON data was appropriately returned.

Comment: It's disturbing that no error was thrown. That's the kind of passive-agressive bull$&!+ I would expect from PHP.